# Facebook api batch request

Tags: ios, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Now I've got simple request to Facebook api:

```
me/feed?fields=type,story,caption,message,picture,comments&limit=20&offset=0
```

It works fine, but in the comments section, there are message, name and user id who post this comment, but I also need a photo-link. Of course I can send more requests to get user-photo. But I think it would be silly decision. Maybe there is way to send fql or batch request to get all fields I need in one request?

P.S. I already know how to do it with ruby, but i need some example which I can use in ios app.

Edit: Also I've got simple example, which do a little more detailed listing, but also without photo. What I should add to request2, to get photo?

```
    JSFacebookRequest *request1 = [JSFacebookRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed?   fields=story,message,comments&offset=15&limit=5"];
    [request1 setName:@"get-field"];
    JSFacebookRequest *request2 = [JSFacebookRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"?ids={result=get-field:$.data..id}"];
    [facebook fetchRequests:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:request1, request2, nil]  onSuccess:^(NSArray *responseObjects) {
        NSLog(@"Responses:\n%@", responseObjects);
    } onError:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your situation, but it seems to me that you're over-complicating things. If you've got the user id, you can build the needed URL like so:

`https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/picture`

If that doesn't give you the desired image size, there are other options listed [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/). (See the 'images' parameter, for example.)